# TensorFlow - show all variables in session

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have played a little

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.Variable([1.0, 2.0])
initializer = tf.global_variables_initializer()
session.run(initializer)
x
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32_ref>
y = 2 * x
y
<tf.Tensor 'mul:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32>
z = y + 1
z
<tf.Tensor 'add:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32>
v = session.run(x)
sess.run(initializer)
v = sess.run(x) 
print (v)
[ 1.  2.]
v1 = sess.run(z)
print (v1)
[ 3.  5.]
v = sess.run(x)
```

I have 3 variables x,y,z.Is it possible to show all the variables defined with one command from prompt? 
If I try what Jonas suggested

```
new = tf.trainable_variables()
print (new)
[<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

Comment: You can call `tf.trainable_variables()`.

Comment: Take a look at my edit,this doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tf.trainable_variables()` prints out all the trainable variables in your graph, which in your case, is only x. When you're doing `y = 2 * x`, this is actually implicitly defining a constant value `mul/x`, and taking in the original variable as a `Variable/read`

If you run the following code:

```py
x = tf.Variable(1)
y = 2 * x
z = y + 1
for v in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node:
  print v.name
```

You will get the following output:

```
Variable/initial_value
Variable
Variable/Assign
Variable/read
mul/x
mul
add/y
add
```

These are all the nodes in your graph. You can use this to filter out all the relevant information that you need. Specific to your case, I wouldn't call `y` and `z` variables.

Note that this is getting all the information from a graph and not a session. If you'd like to get it from a particular session, you'd need to get the relevant session and call `sess.graph`.

As a last note, the above example used `v.name`, but each graph node actually has more attributes, such as `name`, `op`, `input`, `device`, `attr`. Refer to the [API](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/tool_developers/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but what's wrong with this?

```
print(sess.run([x, y, z]))
```